# plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found. android studio jni sample

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-ndk

I am trying to follow the android-studio-jni tutorial from the following link:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-studio-jni/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#2

The simple android app works fine but as soon as I change the classpath to the gradle-experimental as suggested in the tutorial, i get the above mentioned error. I did look at other SO questions related to this but none of them solved my issue.

These are the only changes I made(as done in the tutorial example):

In build.gradle (Module:app) file:

```
`proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),` `'proguard-rules.pro'`
```

replaced with :

```
proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'))
```

In Gradle-wrapper.properties (Gradle Version):

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

replaced with

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

In build.gradle (Project:Samples) file:

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```

replaced with

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.9.3’
```

**Update:**

As suggested by @Hetfieldan24 , my mistake was not having the correct plugin type.
Once I modified it, I am now getting the following error:

```
Error:(3, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments [build_90xijo5xugofjl1c4u81bbnlj$_run_closure1@e9e4277] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Files:

build.gradle (Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.polyyai.user.samplejniapp1"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'))
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

build.gradle (Project:Samples)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.9.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Gradle-wrapper.properties (Gradle Version)

```
#Sat Aug 19 17:05:08 EDT 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you replace apply plugin: 'com.android.application' with apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'? Please, post your build.gradle files.

Comment: Hi Hetfieldan24, thanks for the response. that was my mistake. i fixed that and now i am getting the following error Error:(3, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments [build_90xijo5xugofjl1c4u81bbnlj$_run_closure1@e9e4277] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: also i am trying to add my files but the formatting is all messed up.i will post them once i figure out the formatting issue

Comment: never mind.again it's my mistake